# How to programmatically change button text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to programmatically change the text of a button. I have a number of buttons in the name format `btnXXX` where `XXX` is a number.

```
databaseFunc.SelectThings("uspSelectCategoryNames", noParam, noValue);
dataTable = databaseFunc.dataTable;
for (int x = 0; x < dataTable.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    btn[x].Text = dataTable.Row[0][0].ToString();        
}
```

How do I get the button with name `btnXXX` in this assignment: `btn[x]`?

Comment: But wheres your code for button? haven't you program it?

Comment: What is the result? Is there an error message? What happens and what exactly is the problem? Pleas show the definition of `btn`.

Comment: do you want to change the NAME or the TEXT of the Button? And do i understand you correct, that you read N categories form your DB and want to create a Button for every categorie you read?

Comment: The name of the buttons are btn0, btn1, etc. So yeah, I'm trying to change the text of the buttons as the loop goes. If that makes sense?

Comment: you're using .Text and you want to change name? why not use .Name?

Comment: No, no haha I'm trying to change the text of the button. I'll just draw it out, I guess. The only thing that changes is the number so it corresponds to the button name. So here's what happens in the loop:

btn0.Text = something
btn1.Text = something else

Comment: I think i know what he means, he has btn0,btn1 and btn3 and want to access the textproperty by using btn[x].Text.
If that is correct that the short answer is that this wont work. If you use reflection you can however do something similar

Comment: Yeah, exactly! ^ That's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create an array containing the buttons. You can easily retrieve them using an index:

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[] { btn0, btn1, btn2 };

buttons[0].Text = "abc";
```

This will set the `Text` of the first button.

Another option is to use [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the control with a specific name. Note that the `true` in the `Find` call makes it search the child controls too:

```
Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find("btn0", true);

Button b = matches.Length > 0 ? matches[0] as Button : null;

if (b != null)
{ }
```

Comment: To access them by a string use a Dictionary<string, Button>!

Comment: @TaW: I don't see the added value of `Find`.

Comment: @TaW: Compared to the possibility of making mistakes, I doubt the usefulness. If you have a lot of operations on it, it could have a performance gain. I prefer the first way, since `int x` is the actual base.

Comment: I guess I misread the question; I thought he wanted to change the Name dynamically..

Comment: @TaW: That was a typo. See the comments.

Comment: Right, but that woulnd't stop folks from asking for it  ;-)